# Transparent image over cell with PHP content

Tags: php, overlay, cell, transparent, watermark

I have some code that checks a database and returns an image based on certain criteria. The image is always returned and displayed at 178x134px. The code that pulls the image into the cell is this...

```
<td><?php printAcct(1); ?></td>
```

I have a transparent image with an icon in the top left corner that I would like to lay on top of the returned image sort of like a watermark. I cannot seem to find any simple method to do this, and the difficult methods I have tried, fail because the image I want to overlay the transparent / watermark image on top is pulled in via php.

I found this code here on this website....

```
<style>

.solid {
   background-image: url('image1.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 178px;
   height: 134px;
   z-index:1;
}

.transparent {
   background-image: url('overlay.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 178px;
   height: 134px;
   z-index:1000;
}
</style>


<div class="transparent">&nbsp;</div>
```

Which does exactly what I want to do, however it doesn't work when I wrap the transparent div around the php call like this...

```
<td><div class="transparent"><?php printAcct(1); ?></div></td>
```

The part that makes this a little tricky is the fact that the php call returns an image and makes it clickable to a certain link (based on the image) and that needs to be maintained while I place the watermark image on top.

I'm not much of a programmer but can tinker with code decently, so I would really appreciate some help or being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: So... the problem is that the transparent overlay image is disabling the clickable link on the underlying PHP-pulled image, am I right?

Comment: http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2008/11/watermark-your-images-with-another.html

Comment: When I wrap that code around my php call, it doesn't work. I'm looking for anything that will do what I need, this code was a simple example of the idea.

Comment: *What* doesn't work? That's not clear.

Comment: MadBurn: Thanks, but that looks like it is processing two images and returning a new one, which isn't what I want to do. The php is displaying an image from another server.

Comment: Please, tell me in a single line, what is the problem: Does PHP throw an error? Does the link become un-clickable? Is the overlay not lining up with the image?

Comment: The php call for printAcct doesn't display anything when I run it with the code above. Again, It doesn't matter if it's this code or something else, this code is just an example of what exactly it is im trying to do.

Comment: And does the PHP call work when called individually?

Comment: Yes works flawlessly. When I add the transparent div, it returns just the transparent div content (overlay.png) but not the data from the php call

Answer (score 0):

I've made a JS-Fiddle with the code to achieve what you want. But it needs DIVs to work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/6uPTa/

If you can clarify how your code differs from the above, I can edit this answer and provide the changes.

EDIT: The letter A is underlying, and the "pet products here" is the watermark.

Comment: I tried applying that but it didn't return the php called image, and it displayed the overlay image as 'broken' even though the url for the image is correct.

How can I send you a private message with the link to the page I'm working on and the link to it's txt version so that you can see the source?

Comment: On StackOverflow, I do not think there is a PM feature. You can contact me on my email, and I'll try to help out :) adityamenon90@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you so much, I just emailed you from nickvancouver @ gmail, hope you can help me solve this one!